# Convert timestamp to datetime from string in android

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp

My server response "Nov 27, 2011 07:00am". Then I put this variable.

```
String fecha="Nov 27, 2011 07:00am"
```

but I need in this format:

```
String fecha="2014-11-27 07:00am";
```

Then I want to save this string in SQLite as Date.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. Your questions have been handled on hundreds of other Questions and Answers.

Answer (score 0):

In sqllite you cannot store date and time directly, so you are left with 2 options
**1) Convert it into milliseconds

2)Save it as a string.**
I personally prefer the first one as it it more elite, here's  the code to do the above .

```
    public static long convertDateToMilliSeconds(String inputDate){
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //throw new IllegalAccessException("Error in parsing date");
            }
            return date.getTime();
        }
     public static Date convertMilliSecondToDate(long milliSeconds){
       Date date= new Date(milliSeconds); 
       return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this doc about [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and parsing [Date Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html). You can even use a longer route that involves splitting the string, and re-arranging it into the format that you desire.